# assign out parameter totalRecords when using caching

Tags: asp.net, caching, asp.net-membership

I'm using asp.net **Sqlmembership.GetAll()** method ( paging overload ) . now I want to add a **caching layer** to cache results but there is problem with GetAll method's **out parameter** that returns the total number of records . how can I assign a value to **totalRecords** parameter when data are retrieved from cache ?

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct this little flow will help you to achieve your goal

This is a basic flow:

1. When you want to access the cached object, ask it to the cache provider
2. If the object is not null, then cast to the correct type and return the object from the cache (in this case, the list of users). End process
3. If the object is null then

   1. Retrieve the object from its original source (using the `GetAll` methods)
   2. Save the retrieved object to the cache
   3. Return the retrieved object. End process

In any case, I would recommend you to work with a custom domain class instead of the `MembershipUser` class

This is a basic example:

```
    public IEnumerable<DomainUser> GetDomainUsers()
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Current;
        var cache = context.Cache;
        var domainUsers = cache["domainUsers"] as IEnumerable<DomainUser>;

        if (domainUsers == null)
        {
            domainUsers = Membership.GetAllUsers().OfType<MembershipUser>().Select(x => new DomainUser
                {
                    Email = x.Email,
                    Username = x.UserName
                });

            cache.Insert(
                "domainUsers", // cache key
                domainUsers, // object to cache
                null, // dependencies
                DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), // absoulute expiration
                Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, // slading expiration
                CacheItemPriority.High, // cache item priority
                null // callback called when the cache item is removed
            );

            context.Trace.Warn("Data retrieved from its original source");
        }
        else
        {
            context.Trace.Warn("Data retrieved from cache");

        }

        return domainUsers;
    }
```

Comment: I have problem with GetAllUsers overload that accepts paging parameters : GetAllUsers(int pageIndex, int pageSize,out int totalRecords ) . I don't know how to assign a value to totalRecords parameter when data comes from cache

Comment: I see. But your goal is to cache the records from the database, therefore I think it would be best if you cache all your records and then perform paging on memory. **However**, I would recommend you to think twice what you want to accomplish, if you are thinking to cache it is probably because the query takes too long to execute or the latency between your web and data servers is unacceptable, if this is the case then cache the whole bunch of objects and perform paging in memory. If not, then probably caching won't improve significantly the performance of your site